# How to save multiple images paths in table

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hi please help me am new to laravel I want to store multiple image paths in
table... With this code am unable to save.
Help me for this..

Here in my View

```
  {{Form::open(array('url'=>'businessdirectory/business', 'files'=>true))}}
   {{Form::label('image','Upload Image')}}

   <div class="form-group">{{Form::file('image[]',array('multiple'=>true))}} 

    </div>
    {{Form::close()}}
```

In my Controller

```
   if(Input::file('image'))
     {
     $image = Input::file('image');

     foreach($image as $img) {
     $destination = 'images';
     $filename = $img->getClientOriginalName();
     $path = 'images/'.$filename;
     $uploadSuccess = $img->move($destination,$filename);
     }
     } 
     else
    {
          $path='images/default.JPG';
    }
     $business = new Business();    
     $business->image = $path;

    $business->save();
```

Comment: You need to create an array of paths and then pass the array into `Business::create()` method at the end.

Comment: Hey Thanks Where Should I need to write array.. Path   $path[] = 'images/'.$filename;  Like this I need to metion a..? @Gal..

Comment: You need to create your array inside the `foreach` of course and then outside of the loop use the `Business::create()` to insert all the paths into a table